# How can I access and modify the document object model (DOM) with Webassembly (wasm)?

Tags: javascript, dom, web, webassembly

I know **webassembly** (wasm) is still in its infancy but I'd like to know if and how could I use it to change the DOM (in the same way I'm using Javascript to change the DOM).

Here is the official page:

[Wasm MVP](http://webassembly.org/docs/mvp/)

Comment: Simply import a javascript module that uses the dom and call its functions.

Answer (score 3):

according to [the docs](http://webassembly.org/docs/gc/), DOM access is not supported (as of November 2016) but is planned for the future.

Manipulating the DOM probably won't be supported, if things proceed according to the outline described on that page since references to the DOM are going to be [opaque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_data_type).

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong but they allow use of arbitrary javascript functions and therefore the DOM can be manipulated with those? I think you may be miscontruing opaque as meaning the DOM is const / read-only which would seriously limit the utility of WASM.

Answer (score 3):

A Wasm module can import and call JavaScript functions. A program that wants to manipulate the DOM hence has to come with the right glue layer written in JavaScript. It is more or less the same model as for asm.js code.